# Keras evaluate generator

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to evaluate a keras classifier with a custom generator (the same generator used for training). The predict function works just fine, but the evaluate function throws ValueError: Shapes (None, None, None) and (100, 4, 1, 200) are incompatible

```
output = classifier.predict(x=generator)
evaluate = classifier.evaluate(x=generator)
```

What could cause this? It's the same generator that spits out the same data with the same shape. Tried using evaluate_generator as well, but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was because I added another output.

```
classifier.summary()
classifier = Model(inputs=classifier.input,
               outputs=[classifier.output, classifier.get_layer('attention').output])
classifier.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```